# Intuitive explanation why electrons move from low to high electric potential

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge, potential, conventions

I know almost nothing about physics but am about to learn some electronics.

I have trouble understanding why electrons move from low to high electric potential based on the definition given on the [wikipedia page for electronic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential):

" An electric potential (also called the electric field potential, potential drop or the electrostatic potential) is the amount of work needed to move a unit of charge from a reference point to a specific point inside the field without producing an acceleration "

I don't really understand the math in the article so I was hoping for an intuitive explanation instead.
I've read some places that it's a convention that positive charges moves from high to low potential, but I figured since there exists a definition of electric potential one should be able to derive exactly why negative charges move from low to high electric potential and positive charges move from high to low potential, without having to rely on this convention.

One definition of electric potential I have from my textbook is $V = \dfrac{W}{Q}$ where $W$ is energy and $Q$ is charge. Based on this definition I think I understand why electrons move from low to high potential even if they move from high to low potential energy since the charge makes $V$ negative for electrons, so larger $W$-value gives a lower $V$-value.

But from the definition on the wikipedia page I reasoned like this:

Assume the electric field goes to the left and a positive charge $q_+$ and negative charge $q_-$ both starts at point $P_0$. So a positive charge would travel to the left and a negative charge would travel to the right. Both positive and negative charges moves to where they have lower potential energy. In order to move a charge towards a point in the direction the charge is travelling in the electric field without producing an acceleration, we would need to produce a force in the opposite direction. It is my understanding that then the work produced would be negative. I illustrate my reasoning:

$P_B^+ \quad P_A^+ \quad q_+ P_0 q_- \quad P_A^- \quad P_B^-$

That is, in order to move $q_-$ to $P_A^-$ we would have to "stop" $q_-$ from accelerating and therefore produce negative work. If the work needed to move $q_-$ to $P_A^-$ is $W_A^-$ and the work needed to move $q_-$ to $P_B^-$ is $W_B^-$ then $|W_B^-| > |W_A^-|$ so $W_B^- < W_A^- < 0$.

Therefore $q_-$ moves from higher to lower electric potential with $P_0$ as a reference point.

So when I reason with the definition from the wikipedia page my conclusion becomes that both positive and negative charges moves from higher to lower electric potential.